# VBscripting runtime error using DDT Driver in test complete?

Tags: excel, vbscript, testcomplete

> 'stylesheet1$' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not
>   include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

This is the exact VBscript Runtime error .. please help

Comment: You need to add some context for this question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**stylesheet1** is an odd name for a sheet within an Excel book. Are you sure that you specify a valid name? Most probably, the valid name is just **Sheet1**.

```
  Call DDT.ExcelDriver("d:\Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1", true)
```